# What kind of transformer to use for Japanese Refrigerator if to be used in the Philippines?

Tags: appliances

I can't seem to upload the image of the specification o fthe refrigerator. The refrigerator is a Haier. It is now connected to a 500W, 60 cycle, 110v transformer. The freezer is working but the refrigerator section is not cooling. The lights are even working. I noticed that the refrigerator door is not sticking well but it should still cool a little but it has not.
The refrigerator is 50-60hz.
The thermal somthing consumption is 120/120W. 
The electric motor something conaumption is 70/80W
Voltage is 100v.
Sorry I'm not that good with Japanese, I can't read all that is written in the specs.

Comment: A little more clarity would help.  Is the Philippine power 220/240V 60Hz?  Is the refrigerator meant to run on 110/120V 60Hz?  Is the transformer designed to convert 240V 60Hz to 120V 60Hz?

Comment: What kind of power do you have in your home?  110/220V split-phase?  Or 220V European style single phase?  The Philippines are currently in the middle of changing over from one to the other.

Comment: I checked with my electric company, they said the power supplied to my house is 220/240V 60hz. I'm not sure how to check how the refrigerator is meant to run. But based on the spec sticker in the refrigerator there is no 110 written in it. So, I don't know if it is running on110/120V. The tranformer input is 220V, and output is 110V.